# What does $e$, $i$ and $\vec{p}$ mean in this formula?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields, dipole

I've found a formula to calculate the $\vec{E}$-field vector of a Hertzian dipole in the far field (don't know if that's the correct term) to draw and simulate the field lines.

Link to my source: https://physik.cosmos-indirekt.de/Physik-Schule/Hertzscher_Dipol

This formula is a simplyfication that just relates to the far field and is not an exact value.

$$\vec{E} = \frac{\omega^2}{4\pi\epsilon c^2r} (\vec{n}\times\vec{p}) \times \vec{n}\cdot e^{i(\rho-\omega t)}  \quad \text{with} \quad \rho=\frac{\omega r}{c}$$

As said I don't know what $\vec{p}$ , $e$ and $i$ mean.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Hint (very basic): Euler's formula.

Comment: If wherever you found that formula didn't define its variables, then I wouldn't trust it anyway.

Comment: *I've found a formula*  Found *where* ?  A reference or link would be useful.

Comment: The formula looks suspicious to me. Are you sure you copied all of it? In the exponential there seems something to be missing, at least an $r$, may be more.

Comment: By the way: The preferred way here to show formulas is [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Dipole_radiation).

Comment: Okey after these Hints is got it that i is an imaganary unit. But how am I supposed to get a value out of this that the computer can draw if there is a imaginary part in the answer?

Comment: The only symbols not defined on your linked page are the imaginary unit $i$ and the Euler constant $e$. Note that one of your $p$ is a $\rho$. Perhaps you would fare better with a source in English rather than German?

Comment: @SimonTrakis Just take the real part of $\vec{E}$ for drawing and ignore the imaginary part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\vec{p}$ ... electric dipole moment
2. $e$ ... Euler's constant
3. $i$ ... imaginary unit

---

As others have already mentioned: don't confuse $\vec{p}$ with $\rho$